# Git - Pushing big file gives error, remote: fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Input/output error

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I'm pushing a big big file (1.98 GB) with Git to GitLab, and it returns this error:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 341.73 MiB | 2.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Input/output error
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To https://gitlab.com/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxxxxxxx@gitlab.com/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.git'
```

Is this an issue with Git or with GitLab?

My computer has a 16 GB memory and I use macOS.

Comment: Anything prefixed with `remote:` like that means the error message came from the *other* Git (not your Git). So the answer to "is this an issue with Git or with GitLab" is "yes", because there's another Git on the GitLab side, but whatever the problem is, it's happening over there.

Comment: You can check your gitlab repo's size and limitation. It's mainly caused the your repo's size.

Comment: Why do you have a 1.98GB file in version control anyway?